# Facebook gave me page on many likes but likes count differs

Tags: facebook, web-applications, facebook-like, facebook-social-plugins

I did add fb's like button on my site , after around 70 likes I got fb page for my link in ready made state.
But likes on page & my link differ that to by whole lot margin.
Can anyone explain me how to match both's like count or atleast sync them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming a lot here because your question isn't completely clear, but it sounds like you're saying the count on the Like button, and the count of likes on the Admin page for that URL are not matching?
That's expected. The like button count for a URL includes things not included on the virtual 'admin' page for that URL:

See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/ :

> **What makes up the number shown on my Like button?**
>
> The number shown is the sum of:
>
> - The number of likes of this URL
> - The number of shares of this URL (this includes copy/pasting a link back to Facebook)
> - The number of likes and comments on stories on Facebook about this URL
> - The number of inbox messages containing this URL as an attachment.